# How do I remove the red box on Facebook's permissions page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We recently added Facebook integration to our sales process using the Graph API, and despite Facebook stating "*All items in your submission were approved!*", we still display this ugly "Submit for review" red box.

Here's which permissions we request.

```
<fb:login-button size="large"
    onLogin="checkLoginState()"          
    scope="user_friends,user_events,rsvp_event">
```

[image: Here's the red box.]

Here's a screen shot from the account page. You can see we *did* submit for review, and we were accepted. This was 7 days ago. Since there's no one at Facebook to contact about this, we're puzzled. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Which permissions do you ask for when you pop the dialog? I mean which permissions do you list. Not which ones are displayed in the dialog. And the red box is only displayed for developers of the app and no one else

Comment: Is `user_events` listed further down there, below where your screenshot ends …?

Comment: @CBroe It is not. I figured that out after WizKid's post, but I was waiting to get a response from Facebook after my new submission. If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it. Somebody will come across this Googling one day and say "doh!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot does not show `user_events` permission, but in your login button scope you are asking for that permission.

So, if you did not get that permission reviewed yet, that explains the message.